# Normalization of individual values of multicolumn dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, calculation

I have a dataframe containing 100 columns x 72 raws.

df_3

```
                0        1        2               
first_point   458.69   457.71   420.82        
max_point    3654.07  8134.25  7520.39       
0             458.69   457.71   420.82         
1             437.92   339.23   287.35        
2             443.19   303.66   314.83        
3             416.03   315.33   317.84        
4             406.89   306.29   328.26        
5             419.13   334.01   325.01
```

For each column starting from 0,1,2,3... I want to create two variables (nom and den)

```
  (for col0, row0) df_3[0][0] nom=458.69-first_point in col0 (458.69)
  (for col0, row1) df_3[0][1] nom=437.92-first_point in col0 (458.69)

  (for col0, row0) df_3[0][0] dem=max_point (3654.07)-first_point in col0 (458.69)
  the dem remains the same whithin the same column
```

How could I loop the operation required for nom in which the substracted point remains fix while iterating the substraction of the value on each row of the column?
Afterwards I am doing the division between nom/dem

```
if dem !=0:
        norm = (nom / dem)
    else:
        norm = 0
    #we add the value to the final line
    final_line.append(norm)
```

the output for col 0 would be:

```
   0
0  0
1 -0.0065
2 -0.0048508
3 -0.0133505
4 -0.0162735
5 -0.0123804
```

Comment: Can you please share the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, you could simply do:

```
for c in df.columns:
    first_point = df[c].values[0]
    max_point = max(df[c])
    dem = max_point - first_point
    if dem != 0:
        df['norm_' + str(c)] = (df[c] - first_point) / dem
    else:
        df['norm_' + str(c)] = 0
```

However I am wondering if you are confusing different things in your explanation. As you can see here, the nominator of your division has a value depending on the row, but the denominator is fixed. In the cases where you are testing if denominator equals 0, it would set the whole column values to be 0 if you had first_point == max_point.